# Strongly graded algebras with no zero divisors

Tags: gr.group-theory, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, graded-rings-modules

Let $A = \bigoplus_{i \in \mathbb{Z}} A_i$ be a strongly graded unital algebra over $\mathbb{C}$, with no zero divisors. Is it always true that 
$$
m: A_i \otimes_{A_0} A_j  \to A_{i+j}
$$
is an isomorphism?

Comment: For context, for an abelian group $G$ a $G$-graded algebra $A$ is called strongly graded if $A_tA_u=A_{t+u}$ for all $t,u\in G$. (I'm not sure what's the implicit meaning of "algebra": I just guess "associative unital algebra".)

Comment: and the group $G$ does not necessarily have to be abelian.

Comment: yes, algebra means associative unital algebra

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is always an isomorphism of $A_0$-bimodules.

It is a general result for strongly graded rings. It holds for an arbitrary grading group $G$ (not necessarily $\mathbb{Z}$) and does not depend on the presence of zero divisors. For a proof, see Corollary 3.1.2, p.82, from [Methods of Graded Rings](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540207467).