# $\mathbb{Z}$-graded algebras and tensor products

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, homological-algebra, hopf-algebras, graded-rings-modules

Let $A = \bigoplus_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} A_k$ be a not necessarily commutative $\mathbb{Z}$-graded unital algebra over a field $\mathbb{K}$, and assume that it is **strongly graded**:
$$
A_kA_l = A_{k+l}.
$$
In general can it happen that the multiplication does **not** give an isomorphism
$$
A_k \otimes_{A_0} A_l \simeq A_{k+l}?
$$
The map will be surjective since we are assuming the gradind to be strong, but will it be injective?

Comment: What graded algebras do you know? Injectivity is false in *almost* every example one can think of.

Comment: @VladimirDotsenko Most algebras I can think of are not strongly graded anyway (for instance if $A_k=0$ for some (possibly negative) $k$, then $A_0=A_kA_{-k}=0$ and hence $A=0$). Anyway I can see a few ad-hoc counterexamples.

Comment: @YCor you are right. I was thinking about $\mathbb{N}$-graded, apologies. For $\mathbb{Z}$-graded it is way more subtle, as most algebras are non-examples.

Comment: (Actually I was too quick and have no counterexample in mind at the moment)

Comment: I am thinking of geometric examples, for instance the direct sum of algebraic sections of line bundles over the $2$-sphere. Here it all works if I understand it well. I was wanting to know if injectivity is a geometric result, or a general algebra result.

Comment: Take your favourite group with a homomorphism to $\Bbb Z$ and look at its group algebra.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://mathoverflow.net/q/349864/85967

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou Indeed it's answered there, but the question had extra assumptions (also I appreciate here that the definition was included, which allowed me to understand it and think a little about it)

Comment: @YCor, yes i also thought of that (that the other question had extra assumptions). So, yes i agree and this is why i did not vote to close as a duplicate (and i am not willing to). I just thought that it would be useful to leave a relevant comment for reference.

Comment: @KonstantinosKanakoglou You're welcome. It's anyway very timely you had the answer, whose larger generality (grading in a group) is a helpful context.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it cannot happen.

And not only for strongly $\mathbb{Z}$-graded rings; this is always the case for any strongly $G$-graded ring, where $G$ is a group. $A_k \otimes_{A_0} A_l \simeq A_{k+l}$ is an isomorphism of $A_0$-bimodules.

(See: Corollary 3.1.2, p.82, from [Methods of Graded Rings](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540207467)).

Comment: Great, I didn't hope there would be a such nice answer! Thanks a lot!

Comment: You are welcome. And by the way, welcome to MO.

Comment: To be clear, you are saying that it cannot happen that multiplication does not give an isomorphism?

Comment: @Zach Teitler, yes that is right. This is what i am saying. (Following the wording of the OP: "...can it happen that the multiplication does not give an isomorphism..")